# Python: most elegant way to restore class instance attributes to state from __init__

Tags: python, class, inheritance, attributes, restore

What is the most elegant way to reset class instance to the state from just after **init**?
I have a class:

```py
class ParentClass:
    some = "parameters"
    here = None 

    async def run(self, **kwargs):
        pass
```

And I have like 150 sub-classes:

```py
class SubClass(ParentClass):
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       # instance parameters assignment here
       
   async def run(self, param):
       # here something like self.parameter1 = 5 can occur, so instance attribute change
```

OR

```py
class SubClass(ParentClass):
    
    @staticmethod
    async def build(**kwargs) -> 'SubClass':
        param1 = "something"
        param2 = "another_something"
        ...
        return SubClass(param1, param2, ...)
    
    def __init__(self, param1, param2, ...):
        self.param1 = param1
        ...

    async def run(self, param):
        # here something like self.parameter1 = 5 can occur, so instance attribute change
```

I need to conditionally (defined for particular SubClass) reset SubClass instance to state from just after **init** before every **run** method call. I can't create a new instance with same parameters, because:

1. I do not have access to **init** parameters in the place where I call **run**
2. That would hurt performance - sometimes instance is created with **build** method, which is often like 0.5s to finish.

What is the most elegant way to reset it? I only need to reset parameters set in **init**, they can differ between subclasses.

I thought about something like:

1. create decorator that takes parameter (reset=True/False).
2. use it on **run** method.

Decorator would somehow save copy of attributes in class instance (I have no idea to figure out what parameters have been added in **init**), but only if they are currently set to **None**. If **reset** in decorator is set to True, then it will re-assign these attributes and return **run** call.

Though I am sure that there is better way to solve this issue.

Runnable example, without async:

```py
class ParentClass:
    some = "parameters"
    here = None
    
    def run(self, **kwargs):
        pass 

class SubClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, param1: int, param2: str):
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2

    def run(self, params: dict) -> dict:
        self.param1 += 1
        return params  

instance = SubClass(5, "some_string")
# FROM HERE WE CANNOT CREATE NEW SubClass INSTANCES
instance.run({})
print(instance.param1) # IS 6 AND SHOULD BE 6
instance.run({})
print(instance.param1) # IS 7 AND SHOULD BE 6
```

Comment: Store the state in its own object, such as a dictionary. Save a copy of it when the object is initialized and restore it before running.

Comment: I would rethink the need for `run` to modify the attributes. Do you really need to assign a new value to `self.parameter1`, or can you simply do something like `p1 = self.parameter1` and use `p1` for the rest of the method? Change things because you *need* to, not just because you *can*.

Comment: Could you provide a runnable example that includes initializing and mutating one of these objects?  I have a notion of how to do this with a decorator, but would rather not have to actually build your example for you in order to demonstrate.

Comment: @chepner yep, that would be the easiest way, but that's like refactoring and re-testing a lot of code - work for 2 weeks for our team

Comment: Sometimes, you need to admit your original design was a mistake and fix it.

Comment: @Samwise I added some runnable example - but please be aware that __init__ method of the SubClass can modify given arguments, not necessarily taking args as they are - that's why we need to store configuration after __init__

Comment: Your class's `__init__` method should probably save the *original* values of the parameters separately form the parameters that `run` modifies.

Comment: @chepner that's an implementable idea, now the question is how to implicitly restore them between every **run** call

Comment: You'll need to add a separate method that does so and call that either at the beginning of `run` or before each call to `run`.

Comment: @chepner okay, but that's again a lot of modifying code, then testing and so on - in the case if it is called at the beginning of **run**. It cannot be called from outside - service has to be unaware

Comment: This could be an XY problem. *Why* do you want to execute `run` without accepting what `run` does?

Comment: @Dawidek is it really a lot of code modification? Sounds like a few lines to me. Of course, there will always be some frictions to this sort of stuff, but that is the consequence of the original decisions that were made. There isn't some magic solution that will allow you to modify the behavior of the code you did with zero friction, most of the time.

Comment: So, it could be something as simple as, at the end of `__init__`, `self._original_state = vars(self).copy()`, then at the end of `run`, something like `vars(self).update(self._original_state)`